# Remove all the Kafka ACLs

Tags: apache-kafka, acl

Do you know any command to remove all the available ACLs from Kafka? 
If you added literal ACLs to Kafka, when you want to remove it you cannot use prefixed or ... (it just doesn't match with the literal ACLs).

Thanks.

Comment: I assume you're using the default ACL provider? If so, then the commands would probably require a direct Zookeeper connection

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `--remove` flag of kafka-acl tool, which removes all the acls applied to the topic. Simply loop the command through all the topics.

for each TOPIC in topicList:

```
./kafka-acls --authorizer kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer \
--authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=$ZOOKEEPER \
--topic $TOPIC --remove
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `kafka-acls --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 --remove --topic *`. The `--topics` argument accepts wildcards:

```
--topic <String: topic>                  topic to which ACLs should be added or 
                                           removed. A value of * indicates ACL  
                                           should apply to all topics.
```

Answer (score 0):

The proposed solutions did not work for me, the ACLs were not deleted unless they matched exactly.

My workaround was to use the AdminClient directly:

```
        try (AdminClient adminClient = AdminClient.create(props)) {
            adminClient.deleteAcls(
                    List.of(new AclBindingFilter(ResourcePatternFilter.ANY, AccessControlEntryFilter.ANY)));
        }
```